# Ionic Client network socket disconnected

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

I have this problem I also use VPN to another country but still have the following error:

```
 PS C:\Users\Arashsoft\Desktop\ionic\start_angular> ionic start

Every great app needs a name!

Please enter the full name of your app. You can change this at any time. To bypassthis prompt next time, supply name, the first argument to ionic start.

? Project name: test

Pick a framework!

Please select the JavaScript framework to use for your new app. To bypass this
prompt next time, supply a value for the --type option.

? Framework: Angular

Let's pick the perfect starter template!

Starter templates are ready-to-go Ionic apps that come packed with everything you
need to build your app. To bypass this prompt next time, supply template, the
second argument to ionic start.

? Starter template: blank
√ Preparing directory .\test - done!

Downloading and extracting blank starter

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

     Ionic CLI update available: 5.4.16 → 6.2.1
The package name has changed from ionic to @ionic/cli!

       To update, run: npm uninstall -g ionic
           Then run: npm i -g @ionic/cli
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was
established

at connResetException (internal/errors.js:570:14)
at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1361:19)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:215:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
```

I also uninstalled node js and install again and also check the newest version 13.11.0 but the same error occurs.

Here is my ionic info:

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI : 5.4.16
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : not installed    native-run  : not installed
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v12.16.1    npm    : 6.13.4    OS     : Windows 10

Comment: anyhelp to fix this?

Comment: Try to update your CLI. `npm uninstall -g ionic`  Then run: `npm i -g @ionic/cli`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib hi does't work

`code
? Project name: testarash

Let's pick the perfect starter template!

Starter templates are ready-to-go Ionic apps that come packed with everything you 
need to build your app. To bypass this prompt next time, supply template, the     
second argument to ionic start.

? Starter template: blank
√ Preparing directory .\testarash - done!
| Downloading and extracting blank starter
Error: read ECONNRESET

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by changing ip and dns to Netherland

shame on sanction against iran..

Comment: Create Issue on GitHub repo.